# Troubleshooting why my Android phone is rebooting (Nexus S)

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, reboot

It seems to happen when I'm using Pandora. But then again, I'm always using Pandora. It also reboots so quickly that sometimes, I do not notice.

Is there a way to see what caused the last reboot?

Comment: *(Just thought I'd add.)* My milestone reboots randomly about thrice a week. I've noticed it can happen at any moment with any app (sometimes even while it's sleeping). And the reboot is almost instant: it doesn't shut down smoothly, it simply blacks out and immediately starts booting again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Engadget has just reported that the Nexus S is having issues with random reboots (http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/15/nexus-s-suffering-from-random-data-loss-reboots/) and apparently fixes are coming.

To see the log you can get the following app:

[aLogCat](http://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat)

[image: aLogCat QR Code]

Comment: Thanks. However, I'd still like to know what were the causes of the last reboots. Is there not a log of this?

Comment: @Nimmy You can make your own log, google "android logcat"

Comment: alogcat was removed, do you know of any alternative? Maybe [Logcat Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.logcatapp)?